# How to obtain endpoint of ELB,RDS made using terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create an environment variable to be used in the application by acquiring the endpoint of ELB, RDS made using terraform.

Currently I am trying to get an endpoint with aws cli as follows, but is there a simpler way?

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier xxxx | jq '.DBInstances[].Endpoint.Address'
aws elb describe-tags --load-balancer-name xxxx | jq '.TagDescriptions[].LoadBalancerName'
```

For example, how to obtain the endpoint of the AWS stack created on terraform

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please go through terraform documents for the resources you are targetting.

[aws_db_instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html)

[aws_elb](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html)

In each document, there is a part called `Attributes Reference`, I personally call them `available output variables`

So if you need rds endpoint from terraform as output

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.6.17"
  instance_class       = "db.t1.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name = "my_database_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.6"
}

output "rds_endpoint" {
  value = "${aws_db_instance.default.endpoint}"
}
```

You should be fine to do the same for ELB.

Sometime, not all attributes are updated in terraform document, you can follow below answer to find the right output variables

[How to get an instance id / arn of an existing ec2 instance via terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518531/how-to-get-an-instance-id-arn-of-an-existing-ec2-instance-via-terraform/46520415#46520415)

Comment: is it possible to pass the rds_endpoint variable to an ec2 instance through an environment var?